# React-Native reacts differently when not debugging remotely

Tags: javascript, react-native, remote-debugging

```
<Text style={s.date}>{ new Date(this.props.order.ordered_at).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: '2-digit', month: 'short' }) }</Text>
<Text style={s.time}>({ new Date(this.props.order.ordered_at).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true }) })</Text>
```

Output when JS remote debugging is off

```
02/13/17 (23:51:31)
02/13/17 (23:48:07)
```

Output when JS remote debugging is on

```
Feb 13 (11:51 PM)
Feb 13 (11:48 PM)
```

**What's causing this and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Read the [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) for more information, it explained it very well. As an alternative, you can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) instead of JS date API.

Comment: Its better to use MomentJs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import moment from 'moment';

<Text style={s.date}>{ moment(new Date(this.props.order.ordered_at)).format('ll') }</Text>
<Text style={s.time}>{ moment(new Date(this.props.order.ordered_at)).format('LT') }</Text>
```

will consistently yield

```
Feb 13, 2017 (11:51 PM)
Feb 13, 2017 (11:48 PM)
```

Why doesn't the usual `Date()` way work?

> **JavaScript Runtime**   When using React Native, you're going to be running your JavaScript code in two environments:
>
> - On iOS simulators and devices, Android emulators and devices React Native uses JavaScriptCore which is the JavaScript engine that powers
>     Safari. On iOS JSC doesn't use JIT due to the absence of writable
>     executable memory in iOS apps.
> - When using Chrome debugging, it runs all the JavaScript code within Chrome itself and communicates with native code via WebSocket. So you
>     are using V8.
>
> While both environments are very similar, you may end up hitting some
>   inconsistencies. We're likely going to experiment with other JS
>   engines in the future, so it's best to avoid relying on specifics of
>   any runtime.

So, as mentioned in the comments, it's better to use `momentJS` instead of relying blindly on the JS of the environment doing which can lead to inconsistencies as mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html)

Comment: date-fns is much better alternative to momenjs.  please see https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=moment@2.20.1 vs https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=date-fns@1.29.0

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem till I started to use the following code:

```
moment(`${post.date}+02:00`).
```

Here I had used `+02:00` since the server date is in GMT+2 timezone. You should change it to adjust your server date timezone